# How to filter child nodes using jmespath?

Tags: json, null, jmespath

How can I get all properties, expect those with value `null` using jmespath?

```
{
    "foo": 10,
    "bar": null,
    "qux": ["Hello", "World"]
}
```

I'd like the result to be

```
{
    "foo": 10,
    "qux": ["Hello", "World"]
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see there is still no way to filter the keys of a dictionary.  For a list, as you probably know, the answer would be something like `jmespath.search('[?@!=null]', json.loads('[1,null,2]'))`  I see no reason why such a filter could not exist in jmespath but it doesn't.